# How to control two UITextFields' data at the same time?

Tags: swift

I've two `UITextField`s and a `UIButton`. This button gets the value of the filled field. If both fields filled function errors. I've used `isEmpty` method and if statement but it is still not controlling `UITextField`s.

P.S.: I've filled the fields and it alerts as ...cannot be empty.

```
if ICAOCodeField.text?.isEmpty == true && airportNameField.text?.isEmpty == true {
            let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Neither fields cannot be filled", message: "Use only one field", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        } else if ICAOCodeField.text?.isEmpty == false && airportNameField.text?.isEmpty == false {
            let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Neither field cannot be empty", message: "Enter Value", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        } else if ICAOCodeField.text?.isEmpty == true && airportNameField.text?.isEmpty == false {
            primitiveTowersArray = getTowerNames(ICAOCode: getICAOFromAirportName(airportNameField.text!))
        } else if ICAOCodeField.text?.isEmpty == false && airportNameField.text?.isEmpty == true{
            primitiveTowersArray = getTowerNames(ICAOCode: ICAOCodeField.text!)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

**Swift 1.2**

```
if(Your_textfiled1.text == "" && Your_textfiled2.text == "")
{
  let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Neither fields cannot be filled", message: "Use only one field", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
else
{
 // Do something
}
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
 if(Your_textfiled1.text! == "" && Your_textfiled2.text! == "")
    {
      let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Neither fields cannot be filled", message: "Use only one field", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
                presentViewController(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
     // Do something
    }
```